# Is there a way to do focus bracketing on Nikon D90 with Nikkor 105mm f/2.8?

Tags: macro, focus, nikon-d90, bracketing

One feature I loved in my old Canon G6 was the ability to do focus bracketing in macro photography.

Any hope of focus bracketing using my Nikkor 105mm f/2.8 macro lens on my D90 body?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two main reason why you would want to focus bracket.  The first is Focus Stacking where you achieve a **greater depth of field** by combining multiple images with different focal points.  The second is to ensure that you receive a single final image with the **desired focus point**.

You are using this for macro photography so I am assuming that you would like to **stack images** in order to achieve a greater depth of field.

The **Nikon D90 does not have the ability to bracket focus**.  This is one area where many point-and-shoot or pocket digital cameras have a slight advantage to most DSLRs.  You can achieve a similar effect simply by **putting your lens into manual focus mode and racking the focus back and forth for multiple images**.  You also can put the camera into auto mode and simply select a different focus point over multiple image captures, but in practice this will be slightly cumbersome.

Answer (score 3):

I somewhat disagree with **dpollitt** when he says: "Nikon D90 does not have the ability to bracket focus". 
While the body itself lacks this feature, it still allows for remote control, including focus bracketing, when connected to PC. I know of at least two software products for that - Nikon's Camera Control Pro 2 and Helicon Remote.